# Difference in Working Days with decimals

Tags: 2010

I have tried everything possible and cannot get this to work. I want days with 2 decimal points. Here are the methods attempted:

This method gives no decimal points:

```
=DATEDIF([In progress],[Manager approval],"D")
    -IF(WEEKDAY([Manager approval])=7,
    FLOOR((DATEDIF([In progress],[Manager approval],"D")+
    WEEKDAY([In progress]))/7,1)*2,
    FLOOR((DATEDIF([In progress],[Manager approval],"D")+
    WEEKDAY([In progress]))/7,1)*2+1)+
    IF(WEEKDAY([In progress])=7,2,1)
```

This method give no decimal points as well:

```
=DATEDIF([In progress],[Manager Approval],"D")
-INT(DATEDIF([In progress],[Manager Approval],"D")/7)*2
-IF((WEEKDAY([Manager Approval])-WEEKDAY([In progress]))<0,2,0)+1
```

This method does not eliminate weekends however gives decimal points:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Manager Approval])),([Manager Approval]-[In Progress]),0)
```